# Why a DLL built with VS 2017 is asking for 'Visual Studio 2010 Redistributable Package' when using it?

Tags: visual-studio, redistributable

I developed a VB function library using VS2017, and created the DLL.
When another user access to this DLL, it requires 'Visual Studio 2010 Redistributable Package' !
Why? Anything to do to avoid this?

Hints: at the beginning, I have
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Math

and the DLL is also code-signed. Is it the reason?

Comment: That is not the reason.  How you got a dependency on a DLL written in C or C++ is not obvious from the question.

Comment: Yes, project is written in VB, not C. Using VS2017. That's why I wonder how come when using this DLL, it requires a C library, and even more from VS2010 !